# WP8 Tap event handling in c#

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, handler, tap

I've added some UIelements (buttons) programatically to my application interface and i'd like to handle tap events.

I would have done it in my xaml file with

```
<Button Tap="onTap"/>
```

How could I do it in C# ? I don't know how i shall use `Button.Tap=....`

I Have prepared the handler like that :

```
private void onTouch(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            //Cool stuff here
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+=` to attach event handler in C# :

```
MyButton.Tap += onTouch;
```